# How to make a variable with range and i

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to make a variable like this:

```
h = math.exp(**-i) for i in range(1, 17, 1)
```

It is bringing an error, but then how should I write this? Is there a better way than what im trying?

Thanks!

Comment: What value are you expecting? A list? The generator of values?

Comment: Look about list comprehension

Comment: exactly, I would like to have h = [ e**-1, e**-2, ... , e**-16], and I was trying to write it manually but I think this method is way better! Any suggestions?

Comment: @MateoGuajardo, what is `e`?

Comment: The exponential function @Olvin Roght

Comment: Note, stop thinking in terms of *variables*. Variables are just *names that refer to objects*. You want to create *some object*. At the very least, we nee to know the *type of that object*

Comment: @MateoGuajardo, use [`math.exp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.exp). `[exp(i) for i in range(-1, -17, -1)]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I want a list object :) sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Cause question has tag `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
powers = np.arange(1, 17)
h = np.exp(-powers)
h_list = h.tolist()  # if you want list as a result
```

Comment: Thanks @draw, I think this is exactly what I want.. but I have one more problem, when I run your code, it says that I can't use negative integer powers :(

Comment: Why not `np.arange(-1, -17, -1)`?

Comment: not working because of negative values :(

Comment: @MateoGuajardo, `h` consists of 17 positive floats, and where it says "can't use negative integer powers", is it an Error at runtime?

Comment: It is the answer. It works correctly as `[math.exp(i) for i in range(-1, -17, -1)]` that **Olvin Roght** said in the comments. Your can do the same results using `np.apply_along_axis(np.exp, arr=np.arange(-1, -17, -1), axis=-1).tolist()` too. All get your results without any problem. If you want another results you must explain correctly in your question with a sample result.